# из списка dropdown-ul отобразить выбранный пункт выпадающего списка сбоку

Tags: javascript, jquery, список, ul

Прошу помочь вывести выбранный пункт из выпадающего списка рядом с `.dropdown-toggle`.

```js
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.dropup {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropup">
  <div class="dropdown-toggle">Size</div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="">цвет 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">цвет 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">цвет 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="selected"></div>

$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass('open');
  $("#selected").text($(this).text());
});
```